# Is interleaving processes of different programming languages useful?

Tags: java, process, programming-languages, interleave

I was wondering if it could be usefull to invoke different processes of different programming languages?
For example, I have a java application. But I have some heavy calculations to do. So I write a programm in another none JVM language (C, Go, etc.), which can express or handle those calculations better than plain java could, and return the results to the main java application.
I know that for example the Java OpenGL implementation uses C-DLLs to access the OpenGL functionality. But is this necessarily a good approach?

Comment: This is far too broad to find useful answers. Describe a real problem with real choises. And of course show what have already tried.

Comment: I didn't had a specific problem. I just wondered if this is a good decision to make or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native methods. Native methods are used to call another programming languages (like C,C++) within java JVM.